# this.subscribe and Template.instance().subscribe do not work

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using Meteor 1.4.

```
Template.showProducts.onCreated(() => {
  var handle = Meteor.subscribe("products");
  //not working: var handle = this.subscribe("products");
  //not working: var handle = Template.instance().subscribe("products");

  Tracker.autorun(() => {
  //not working: this.autorun

    const isReady = Meteor.ready();
    //not working: this.subscriptionsReady()

    if(isReady){
      const products = Products.find().fetch();
      Session.set("prods", products);
    }
  });
});
```

If I use "this.subscribe", I got:

> Uncaught TypeError: _this.subscribe is not a function

If I use "Template.instance()", I got:

> Cannot read property 'subscriptionsReady' of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an arrow function, then the value of `this` which Meteor tries to pass in is lost. Instead use a regular anonymous function (`function () { ... }`).

You should then use `this.autorun` rather than `Tracker.autorun`. This will ensure that the autorun is cleaned up when the template disappears, and will allow `Template.instance` to work inside the autorun.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're passing the `onCreated` handler an arrow function, which does not allow binding of `this` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)).  As a result, Meteor is unable to correctly bind the template instance it has just created, and your subscriptions (and various other things) will fail.

The fix is just to pass `onCreated` a traditional JS function:

```
Template.showProducts.onCreated(function () {
  ...
```